# MatLab creating and solving objects with coupled differential equations

Tags: matlab, object, math

I am working in MatLab and have these nodes. Each node has a system of coupled differential equations that refers to it with their own initial conditions; however each node's standard set of equations is the same. So the only thing that varies from node to node are the initial conditions.

If the setup was just this, I would put each node through ode15s (stiff system) individually, however I now want to connect each node by adding another differential equation that influences the values of the connected node (so a directed graph). Here is a psuedo code example

```
Connect A -> B by adding dB/dt = f(B, A) to B
Run simulation for A and B over time interval
```

At first I thought to use classes, and create a new instance for each specific node, and then have a method to link two nodes, however I wasn't sure how to solve a system of linked ODE's when they exist within two different objects.

Comment: Sounds like you really want something more like finite differences or finite elements.  The nature of the connection should be a physical thing (e.g. mechanics or diffusion equations).  What are you really trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to simulate some cell networks with connected systems

Comment: The graph you mention suggests that the response from one node is coupled to its neighbors in some way.  There are physics involved.  You either use a mathematical technique to generate global matricies to solve (e.g. transient finite elements) or you do something ad hoc like you're suggesting.